# How to get only perfect matches with blastn?

Tags: bioinformatics, sequence-alignment, blast

I have [installed Blast locally](http://www.blopig.com/blog/2014/04/quick-standalone-blast-setup-for-ubuntu-linux/) and I've configured the nucleotide database to use. I want to search some sequences (from a <kbd>.fasta</kbd>file) in this genome. So I used blastn:

```
blastn -db NewDb -query input.fasta -out blast.txt
```

Then I added some options to require a 100% identity and no gaps:

```
blastn -db NewDb -query input.fasta -perc_identity 100 -ungapped -out blast.txt
```

But I still have some results where only a subpart of the string is matching the genome:

```
BLASTN 2.2.29+

[…]

Database: […].fasta
           20 sequences; N total letters

Query= Mutant M :

Length=226
                                                                      Score     E
Sequences producing significant alignments:                          (Bits)  Value

  chrom19                                                               435   3e-122
  chrom2                                                                429   1e-120

> chrom19
Length=W

 Score =   435 bits (226),  Expect = 3e-122
 Identities = 226/226 (100%), Gaps = 0/226 (0%)
 Strand=Plus/Plus

[…]

> chrom2
Length=Y

 Score =   429 bits (223),  Expect = 1e-120
 Identities = 223/223 (100%), Gaps = 0/223 (0%)
 Strand=Plus/Plus

[…]
```

Both results have an identity score of 100%, but the second result only use 223 of the 226 bases from the input sequence.

What parameters can I use with `blastn` to get only perfect matches, with 100% identity and all the nucleotide bases from the input sequence used?

Comment: From my experience, I don't think this is possible. BLAST was designed to find many distant hits, so it wasn't made for this very strong requirement of identical sequences. But you can probably filter it afterwards, no?

Comment: If you want perfect identity, won't a simple string comparison program (in any language) do the job?

Comment: Yeah I concur with @MarchHo. Just do a string search. You can use `grep`

Comment: this might be of help: http://seqanswers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=27735

Comment: @MarchHo in fact it was my first test, I used BioPython in order to read the genome and sequences. Nothing matched but now I realize it was due to the fact that the sequences can be backwards or complementary of the genome.

Comment: Agree with @MarchHo. Would rather use Perl `=~` operator for matching (used as `$template =~ /query/`) than `grep`. And yes Blastn was not designed for that and will match smaller sequences that are 100% similar.

Comment: This is a `grep` question rather than a blast issue, and nothing much to do with biology. I'm voting to close it as off topic.